# How to use if loop in Jolt?

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I want to use if loop for below scenario in JOLT.

Like if `WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE` value is **2** then

map

- `DESCR_SHIPTO` to **addressName**

and

- `ADDRESS1_SHITPTO` to **addressLine**

If it is possible in jolt then what would the spec look like?

Below is the code

**Input**

```json
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": 2,
              "DESCR_SHIPTO": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
               "ADDRESS1_SHIPTO": "OHIO FARMERS INSURANCE COMPANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
  "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails": {
    "integrationEntities": {
      "integrationEntity": {
        "integrationEntityHeader": {
          "action": "UPSERT"
        },
        "integrationEntityDetails": {
          "poDetails": {
            "poHeader": {
              "shipToAddress": {
                "addressName": "OHIOFARMERSINSURANCECOMPANY",
                "addressLine": "OHIO FARMERS INSURANCE COMPANY"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "WG_SHIP_ADDR_TYPE": {
                    "2": {
                      "#UPSERT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.action",
                      "@(2,DESCR_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressName",
                      "@(2,ADDRESS1_SHIPTO)": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.shipToAddress.addressLine"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```